# How do I access a hash inside an array inside a ruby object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, mongodb, hash, rubygems

I'm using the publicactivity gem to audit activity within my application.

Using MongoDB, and none of the data below is real - but representative of real data.

I shoved in some data like this:

```
"changes" : [
        {
            "oldFirst" : "Aaron2",
            "oldLast" : "Aardvark2",
            "oldCity_id" : "Bogota, TN",
            "oldZip_code" : 38007,
            "oldPhone" : [
                "9993339999",
                "4442224443"
            ],
            "oldStreet1" : "1111 Brighton Clopton St",
            "oldStreet2" : "Suite 100",
            "oldEmail" : [
                "uk@tel.com"
            ],
            "oldType" : "customer",
            "oldLatitude" : "36.1625531",
            "oldLongitude" : "-89.4362431",
            "oldCust_notes" : "",
            "oldAccount_id" : ""
        },
        {
            "newFirst" : "Aaron",
            "newLast" : "Aardvark",
            "newCity_id" : "Brighton, TN",
            "newZip_code" : 38011,
            "newPhone" : [
                "9993338888",
                "4442223334"
            ],
            "newStreet1" : "1111 Brighton Clopton Dr.",
            "newStreet2" : "",
            "newEmail" : [
                "uk@tel.com"
            ],
            "newType" : "customer",
            "newLatitude" : "35.4558615",
            "newLongitude" : "-89.68162079999999",
            "newCust_notes" : "",
            "newAccount_id" : ""
        }
    ]
```

So how do I talk about these elements?

I tried:

```
<%= activity.changes[0]["oldFirst"] %>
<%= activity.changes["oldFirst"] %>
<%= activity.changes.oldFirst %>
<% if activity.changes.any?
  activity.changes.each do |c|
%>
<%= c["oldfirst"] %>
<%end%>
<%end%>
```

etc.

On and on I tried the combinations I know of - and I'm getting this:

```
no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

String into Integer?!  WTF?  It's all string-type data, and I'm trying to access it out as string-type data - I don't understand why it thinks I have or want Integer values.

I can haz help?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had a single bad entry in the DB that was like:

[[{ },{ }]]

Hard to see the double-brackets in the terminal when it's all smashed together pretty tightly using whatever font I use.

This works fine once that single entry is deleted and the rest are left in place (formatted like: [{ },{ }] )

activity.changes[0]["oldFirst"]

etc.

Answer (score 0):

what you are posting here is a JSON data structure, not a Ruby Object.

You'll have to first parse it with JSON, and then you can access it via:

```
 require 'json'
 activity = JSON.parse( json_string )
 activity.changes[0]["oldFirst"]
```

Comment: use `JSON.parse(message)`

Comment: it doesn't matter what you call the variable which holds the JSON string

Comment: This does not work.  I know that it looks like JSON, and MongoMapper may well be returning something it thinks is JSON, but I've parsed at the controller and view levels exactly as you've stated, with activity, activity.changes, activity.changes[0], etc. and this doesn't work.  I pushed the data in to look like this, very much liking working with JSON in general.  Same "no implicit conversion of string into integer" error message.

Comment: if it was happening during a write/save operation, it could be that your Model had an attribute which is Integer, but the data structure you're trying to save has a string in it.  But it seems you're getting this on a read.  Very weird

Comment: This Question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187288/erro-submit-form-no-implicit-conversion-of-array-into-string

this looks like a possible bug in MongoMapper